# PlotRange is not applied after text image conversion is moved

Tags: graphics, rotation

I converted the text image using Rotate and Translate functions.

```
logo[shape_, {fontsize_, p_, rotation_, q_}, opt___] :=  Graphics[Rotate[ Table[Rotate[
 Translate[ Rotate[Text[Style[StyleForm[shape, FontFamily -> "Georgia"], fontsize,  
     Black ], {0, 0}], rotation, {0, 0}], {p, 0}], r, {0, 0}], {r, 0, 2 \[Pi] - 0.01, 2 \[Pi]/q}], 0, {0, 0}], opt, PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600, Background -> White ];  
logo["\[Pi]", {150, -0.1, 5.2, 8}]
```

And I obtained the following output for the input conditions.

[image]

I applied Plot Range to enlarge the graph.

```
logo["\[Pi]", {150, -0.1, 5.2, 8}, PlotRange -> 0.4]
```

[image]

This is not how I want the output to be. Why is the graph not enlarged and the shape changed?

[image]

As shown in the figure above, I wanted to get a full graph within the same size. How should I modify the code?

Comment: `I applied Plot Range to enlarge the graph.`  if you want to use plot range as a parameter to be passed to the function, then why do you have it hardcoded in the function body as `PlotRange->1` as well?

Comment: At first, it is to observe as a whole the state of parallel movement from the position of the initial figure. Afterwards, when I have finished all the movements, I want to enlarge the finally drawn shape without any margins.

Comment: The issue is that the font size is relative to your screen, not relative to plot coordinates (i.e. the same font size will lead to the same size for the letters, no matter what plot range you use). You need to change the font size to something like `350` for it to work